# PartialView on each list items

Tags: partial-views, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a in item list in each row has an edit button, which is supposed to open a partial view with the elements data to edit.
In the loop I use to fill tge datatable, I also create the partial views for each row element.

When I click the buton it always opens the first element partial view, even if I press the Nth element.

How do I get the code to open the corresponding partial view?

Code:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabela_rota">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th>
                Cliente
            </th>
            <th>
                Rota
            </th>
            <th>
                Distância Ideal
            </th>
            <th>
                Ativa
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <partial>
                @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Edit", item);}
            </partial>

            <tr>
                <td width="15">
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_cliente)
                </td>
                <td width="25%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.distancia_ideal)
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.activa)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="openNavEdit()">
                        Editar
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Function:

```
function openNavEdit() {
    document.getElementById("mySidepanelEdit").style.width = "350px";
}
```

View:

```
@model GestaoCircuitos.Models.Rota

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Editar";
}
<div id="mySidepanelEdit" class="sidepanel">
    <div id="top_title">
        <h6 id="nova_rota">Editar Rota</h6>
        <button class="closebtn" onclick="closeNavEdit()">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-row-rotas">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form asp-action="Edit" class="form-rotas">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="id" />
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" />
                    <label asp-for="nome" class="control-label">Nome</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="nome" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="distancia_ideal" class="form-control" placeholder="Distância ideal" />
                    <label asp-for="distancia_ideal" class="control-label">Distância ideal</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="distancia_ideal" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="activa" /> Ativa
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're opening based on ID. An ID attribute needs to be unique throughout a document. If you select on an ID, you'll only get the first element.

You'll have to give each edit modal either a unique ID or a class to select from. Try this:

```html
@model GestaoCircuitos.Models.Rota

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Editar";
}
<div id="sidepanel-edit-@(item.id)" class=" sidepanel">
    <div id="top_title">
        <h6 id="nova_rota">Editar Rota</h6>
        <button class="closebtn" onclick="closeNavEdit(@(item.id))">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-row-rotas">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form asp-action="Edit" class="form-rotas">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="id" />
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" />
                    <label asp-for="nome" class="control-label">Nome</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="nome" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-label-group">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="distancia_ideal" class="form-control" placeholder="Distância ideal" />
                    <label asp-for="distancia_ideal" class="control-label">Distância ideal</label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="distancia_ideal" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="activa" /> Ativa
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Above, we add a unique id for each edit edit form. Then we can reference those unique id attributes in the main template:

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabela_rota">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>

            </th>
            <th>
                Cliente
            </th>
            <th>
                Rota
            </th>
            <th>
                Distância Ideal
            </th>
            <th>
                Ativa
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <partial>
                @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Edit", item);}
            </partial>

            <tr>
                <td width="15">
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_cliente)
                </td>
                <td width="25%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
                </td>
                <td width="15%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.distancia_ideal)
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.activa)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="openNavEdit(@(item.id)">
                        Editar
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and your Javascript would look like:

```js
function openNavEdit(id) {
    document.getElementById("sidepanel-edit-" + id).style.width = "350px";
}
function closeNavEdit(id) {
    document.getElementById("sidepanel-edit-" + id).style.width = "0";
}
```

Something to note, I'm assuming your model has an id attribute.